# Wordpress using custom php files

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've created a search engine on localhost, but am now trying to move the files onto wordpress.

How exactly do I accomplish this with respect to the theme template files and the file manager? I have a search.html document to start off with which calls a search.php for results from MYSQL database.

Meanwhile, i also have a search.inc.php page for the autosuggestions that are also drawn from the database and come up as you type
I have tried inserting the **search.html** code into the header.php file.

The search bar and button are visible, but both the suggestions and the search results do not work. I have tried inserting **search.php** and **search.inc.php** in the same folder as the childtheme and the **header.php** to no avail.

What do I have to do with these files so that they can adequately communicate with my **header.php**?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please create a  page template file in your theme like :

<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/

and when you create a new page select this templete in admin panel.

now you can add any code what you want. this will communicate with you header file


for more details about page template visit :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates
```